# How to open Dialog in PC addin office js

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am trying to open a dialogue from the ribbon button.
I have added a ribbon button triggerDialog to the PrimaryCommandSurface which will execute a function in function-file to open a dialogue

Manifest File:

```
    <DesktopFormFactor>
  <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
  <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
    <!-- Information about this extension point. -->
    <CustomTab id="CustomTab">
      <Group id="Group1">
        <Control>
          <!-- Information about this Control. -->
          <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
            <FunctionName>triggerDialog</FunctionName>
          </Action>
        </Control>
      </Group>
    </CustomTab>
  </ExtensionPoint>

  <!-- You can define more than one ExtensionPoint element as needed. -->
</DesktopFormFactor>
...

<Resources>
  <bt:Urls>
    <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:8080/commands.html" />
  </bt:Urls>

  <!-- Define other resources as needed. -->
</Resources>
```

Following is the function file defined.

```
// Initialize the Office Add-in.
Office.onReady(() => {
  // If needed, Office.js is ready to be called
});

// The command function.
async function triggerDialog(event) {

    Store.saveLocal('dialogData', 'About');
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
        'https://localhost:8080/?tab=dialog',
        {
            height: 60,
            width: 50,
            promptBeforeOpen: true,
            displayInIframe: hostType === HostType.Office_Online,
        },
        (asyncResult) => {
            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                console.log(asyncResult.error.code + ': ' + asyncResult.error.message);
            } else {
                dialog = asyncResult.value;
                dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, receiveMessageFromDialog);
            }
        }
    );
    event.completed();
}

// You must register the function with the following line.
Office.actions.associate("triggerDialog", triggerDialog);
```

Dialog API is works on Office Online[OneDrive document file] and it is not working on PC add-in[word application] via ribbon element

What I am doing wrong here?

My Word add-in project is SPA using React 18.x

for reference purpose attach screenshot :
[image]

Dialog.html
[image]

Comment: You need to give more detail than "is not working". What do expect to see? What do you actually see? At what point do things go wrong?

Comment: I don't see an `Excel.Run` line, that may be your issue.

Comment: Is your ribbon event handler invoked at all? Did you try to run the code under the debugger attached?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers No we don't have here because we are trigger via ExecuteFunction

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev yes it will be invoke via manifest xml file and function file it is in some folder to execute particular function

Comment: Do you see your dialog page in a web browser when navigating to the URL passed as a parameter - `https://localhost:8080/?tab=dialog`?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev yes! if am on Office Online[OneDrive document file]

Comment: No, I mean just navigate to the URL in a web browser, outside of Office 365 apps.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev yes its open blank white page of commands.html but it will open

Comment: So, do you see the expected UI in a web browser?

Comment: no its function file i dont have any html in that it will have script in that and for showing html section in dialog it will have dialog.html page to show some UI

Comment: Maybe that is a problem?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev FunctionFile is called commands.html and dialog.html is called where i have expected UI when Dialog API triggers up and i have attach screenshot for reference purpose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253882/discussion-between-sagar-mistry-and-eugene-astafiev).

Answer (score 0):

The [displayDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=common-js-preview#office-office-ui-displaydialogasync-member(1)) method accepts the initial full HTTPS URL that opens in the dialog. Relative URLs must not be used. See [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) for more information.